# SQL: Long comporating or String, which one is faster

Tags: java, sql, string, performance, long-integer

I'm running this off a java program which connects to my sql server on the same machine. 
Basically I'm trying to call a certain 'String' which can be identified by the string self or by it's already stored 'long'(int64) which is a method that stores an unique long related to the string.

So in this case my question would be, would long comparison at a SQL lookup be faster or wouldn't it matter that much versus String comparison.

```
SELECT * FROM playerAccount WHERE playerName = {string in Java}
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM playerAccount WHERE nameHash = {long in Java}
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: put an index to one of the columns. this one will be faster.

Comment: Did you try it? Generally, if both or neither keys have an index, the second form is likely to be a tiny bit faster - otherwise the one with an index will typically win.

Answer (score 2):

The comparison operation itself is rather negligible.  However, in general in computer code, the comparison of the long is going to use fewer cycles than the comparison for a string.

The reason is that comparing the bits in a numeric value is unambiguous and the code doesn't need to worry about the length of the value.  When comparing strings, the underlying code has to "parse" the strings, character by character, to make the comparison, figure out where they end, and handle collations and character pages.

But, this is rather unimportant.  For speed, you want an index.  And although an index using the numeric value might be an iota faster than an index using a string, this is the *wrong* criteria for choosing which to use.  Your code should be designed to function correctly and to be maintainable.  It is doubtful that an optimization of this sort would ever be necessary to achieve a real-world goal.

Answer (score 0):

Generally comparing long values is faster than comparing string values.
If string and long are stored in a database the problem is not the comparison, but the presence or absence of an index.

So the better solution is using the long value with an index the database.

Please note that if "nameHash" is the hashCode of the field "playerName" the two search don't returns necessarely the same record, infact two players with different names can possible have the same hashCode, so consider exactly what are your needs and eventually update the code.